# Can I connect different items to the same GND pin on an ESP32?

Tags: ground, esp32

Is it good practice to connect two or more devices to the same ESP32 GND pin? For example, I have one MAX6675 and one Interfaz I2C, each one requires a GND connection, but my 30-pins ESP32 only has one single GND pin.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really have a choice....     What really matters is the magnitude and frequency of the ground currents.  Any current that leaves the ESP32 via any I/O has to come back to it through that ground pin.   Only you can decide if the mixing of currents will cause problems or not. Having a bypass capacitor as close as possible to that ground pin and connecting to ESP32's VCC will help alot.

Comment: what sort of esp32 do you have? how are you making connections?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I have a development board ESP-WROOM-32. I am using pin 3v3 and gnd. I am using a breadboard with dupont cables.